# How am i routing the paramaters wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is what i send to the server

```
    async function sendInfo(){
      const info = {info: `${inp1.value}`};
      const response = await fetch(`wiki/${info}`)
     const data = await response.json();
    }
```

This is what how i handle the response in the server:

```
app.get('/wiki/:info', async (req, res)=>{
  const data = await req.params;
  console.log(data)

  res.json(data)
})
```

This is how i try to route the data from the server

```
 async function get(){
     const response = await fetch('/wiki/:info')
     const data = await response.json();
     console.log(data)
   }
```

when i console.log(data), i just get {info: [object Object]}, i dont understand why

Comment: Think about what putting an object into a string ```(`wiki/${info}`)``` gives you.

Comment: yes, but i have to put an object there, or else it will become invalid. The fetch cannot accept a normal string there.

Comment: `fetch` can **only** accept a normal string there! The output of a template literal is a *normal string*.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create an object and stringify it (which gives you (`"[object Object]"`). Just send the string value.

```
const response = await fetch(`wiki/${inp1.value}`)
```

(Assuming `inp1.value` is a string)

Comment: yes, this works, but in the get() function i only recieve "info" when i console.log(data), can you explain why?

Comment: Or is there no point in having the get() function? Could i just retrieve the data from the server in the sendInfo function...

Comment: @Mr.Ulis —`sendInfo` and `get` both make requests to the end point. `sendInfo` sends the value of `inp1.value`. `get` sends the hard coded string `":info"`. The `get` function does seem pointless.